# postman when testing GET it returns 200 but with an empty body

Tags: node.js, api, express, get, postman

When I m trying to test my GET API using postman it returns 200 but with an empty body, The data I'm expecting to get do not show up.

Find my server.js file and the screenshot of POSTMAN result

```
app.get('/api/articles/:name', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const articleName = req.params.name;

        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
        const db = client.db('my-blog');

        const articleInfo = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name: articleName })
        res.status(200).json(articleInfo)

        client.close()
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'error connecting to db', error })
    }

})
```

[image]

Comment: have you checked the value of `articleInfo` in your code? you can put a `console.log` or run the application in debugging mode.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting "Undefined" Still trying to troubleshoot it, I suspect my database connection because the data normally comes from the database.

Comment: i reviewed your code in my machine and it worked fine, check your collection name is ending with 's' or not example: articles not article

Comment: So, there is nothing wrong with your code. I believe two scenarios are possible, having trouble with DB connection (check parameters) or DB has no match with the given articleName

Comment: @PrakashBhosale 
Ohkay, My collection's name is correct Thanks.

Comment: are you getting req.params.name?

Comment: @PrakashBhosale Yes, I'm getting req.params.name but the thing is I'm not getting articleInfo, it's still undefined.

Comment: don't you use mongoose ORM?

Comment: @PrakashBhosale Nope, I m not.

Comment: @PrakashBhosale You can have a look into it at the following link.   https://github.com/Gracekal91/api-troubleshoot

Comment: you have used import instead of require, don't use import in nodejs.

Comment: Yeah, That first thing that came in my mind, As I was following a tutorial that's y I have left it the way it is. Thanks  @PrakashBhosale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i have updated your code as below and please move your server.js outside of /src folder. its working now.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb");
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/api/articles/:name', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const articleName = req.params.name;
        MongoClient.connect(url, async (err, db) => {
            const client = db.db('article');
            const articleInfo = await client.collection('articles').findOne({title: articleName})
            res.send(articleInfo)
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error connecting to db', error });
    }

});
app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Listening on port 8000'));
```

Comment: please vote answer as a useful, if it is a solution. thank you in advance